# Failure: Cannot find module handler AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, serverless

Hello I am trying to setup a new serverless graphql project but the `serverless.yml` file doesn't find my handler, which is in `src/graphql.ts`

It throws an error like this:

```sh
Failure: Cannot find module '/Users/VIU/Projects/am/src/graphql'
```

The `src` is in the root directory and the path is correct, so I don't understand what is going on.

The `serverless.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
graphql:
  handler: src/graphql.graphqlHandler
  events:
    - http:
        path: graphql
        method: post
        cors: true
    - http:
        path: graphql
        method: get
        cors: true
```

And the graphql handler file like this:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from "apollo-server-lambda"

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

// Provide resolver functions for your schema fields
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello world!',
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler();
```

I've also tried

```js
module.exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler();
```

```js
export const graphqlHandler = server.createHandler();
```

But none of that seems to work either.

Has someone any idea of what I am doing wrong? Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run an AWS Lambda function with a Node.js runtime, you'll need to provide a `.js` file as its handler. Specifically, when using TypeScript and the Serverless framework, that means that the `handler` field must refer to the compiled file name, namely, ending with a `.js` extension.

One option for you to resolve this is to simply change the `handler` field to point to the compiled version of your file. For example, given the following structure:

```
├── am
│   ├── built
│   │   └── graphql.js
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       └── graphql.ts
└── serverless.yaml
```

The correct `handler` field is:

```
graphql:
  handler: built/graphql.graphqlHandler
```

However, another option which I believe is the preferred one (and possibly what you were originally aiming for) is to use the [serverless-plugin-typescript](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-typescript) plugin of the Serverless framework. That should reduce your efforts and allow you to use TypeScript almost seamlessly. There is actually an [example](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-typescript-apollo-lambda) provided by Serverless that is very similar to your need and I think you can find useful.

Comment: Super! that is what I was looking for, thanks!